# Prototype - function not found

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
function Tools() { }
Tools.prototype.foobar = function() {
   return 'a';
};

alert(Tools.foobar());
```

And this code returns an error that the `foobar` function was not found. Why is that so? It works without the prototype keyword.

Also, what's the difference? As far as I know I can use prototype keyword, and not use it. If it was an object I could understand that it's inheritance, but what about here?

Comment: You have to create `object` of `Tools` to call `foobar()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not set the property `foobar` on `Tools`, but instead you set it on `Tools.prototype`, which means it won't be available on `Tools`. If you want to call it on `Tools`, you'd have to set it there:

```
Tools.foobar = function() { ... };
alert(Tools.foobar());
```

The purpose of `prototype` is to specify which properties need to be contained by instances of the function. Therefore, if you want to access these properties, you should create a new instance of the function, with the `new` keyword.

```
Tools.prototype.foobar = function() { ... };
var tools = new Tools();
alert(tools.foobar());
```